# Can't understand a behaviour

Tags: php, codeigniter, helper

Why is it that even though my code is like this:

```
if ( ! function_exists('get_values')){
    global $str;
    function getValues($getThem, $tpar, $vpiso, $tcomi, $tgas, $ttotal){
            $totalPares = $tpar;
            $ventasPiso = $vpiso;
            $totalComisiones = $tcomi;
            $totalGastos = $tgas;
            $totalTotal = $ttotal;
            $str = $totalPares . "," . $ventasPiso . "," . $totalComisiones . "," . $totalGastos . "," . $totalTotal;
            return $str;
    }

    function getEm(){
        return $str;
    }
}
```

I can't override the value of $str. It always prints ¨a¨ if I try to echo it, and inside the "getEm" function it says it's an undefined variable.

This is the helper file in the codeigniter framework.

**EDIT**

which still gives me this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: str
>
> Filename:
>   helpers/helper_common_functions_helper.php
>
> Line Number: 15

Comment: at least `global $str;` must be *inside* the function, not outside/before of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
global $str;
```

You need to research variable scoping. Functions have their own scope unless you have `global $variable` at the start to access the variables outside that function. Please also note, using global variables is a "nono" and should be avoided at all cost.

```
function getValues($getThem, $tpar, $vpiso, $tcomi, $tgas, $ttotal){
        global $str;
        $totalPares = $tpar;
        $ventasPiso = $vpiso;
        $totalComisiones = $tcomi;
        $totalGastos = $tgas;
        $totalTotal = $ttotal;
        $str = $totalPares . "," . $ventasPiso . "," . $totalComisiones . "," . $totalGastos . "," . $totalTotal;
        return $str;
}
```

Comment: I tried doing the global $str; I still get the "undefined variable" error =/

Comment: @Luis Armando See again. I posted an example above. Again, I cannot stress enough global variables should be avoided.

Comment: You can't avoid global variables, they are always there ;)

Comment: I'll try and implement the class like the answer above, still just to know after doing what I did and in order for $str to be available in my other function should I also add it like: function getEm(){global $str;return $str;} ? I wonder because I tried this but I get that $str is an empty space

Comment: @hakre unless you're confusing global variables with CONSTANTS. Global variables can and should be avoided. If you need to access something "globally", it should be a constant, and it's best to use these CONSTANTS (not variables) for like BOOTSTRAP'ing an application. Variables (vary) imply changing data.

Comment: @Luis Armando ahh!!!! you're confusing functions with classes; they are not the same thing. I actually like the getter methods used by @KingCruch below.

Comment: @Luis Armando: Yes, see my answer as well, I left markers in the code. You are heading into the right direction.

Comment: @FinalForm: What should I avoid? Global variables? ;)

Comment: @hakre yes totally. Man the days of spaghetti code should stay in the past. I don't want these developers to learn doing things the wrong way right off the bat. Global variables ... or GLOBAL CHAOS :-D

Comment: @FinalForm: You know what's better than spaghetti code? When some double-O cracks apply the big ball of mud antipattern on their code-base. That really rocks, but it's far away from being as delicious as plain old spaghetti code, even crushed patterns on top of something can look crispy as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a class out of it, if you want to want to keep a state within a certain scope. `global` is not recommended

```
class MyClass {
  private $str = "a";

  public function getValues($getThem, $tpar, $vpiso, $tcomi, $tgas, $ttotal){
        $totalPares = $tpar;
        $ventasPiso = $vpiso;
        $totalComisiones = $tcomi;
        $totalGastos = $tgas;
        $totalTotal = $ttotal;
        $str = $totalPares . "," . $ventasPiso . "," . $totalComisiones . "," . $totalGastos . "," . $totalTotal;
        return $str;
  }

  public function getEm(){
    return $this->str;
  }
}
```

Then you need to instanciate the class before you can use it (of course), but you keep your scope clean

```
$x = new MyClass;
echo $x->getEm();
```

If you create the class only with static properties and methods you don't need to instanciate it (`MyClass:getEm()`).

Answer (score 0):

The globals looks misplaced, maybe this is of help:

```
if ( ! function_exists('get_values')){
    function getValues($getThem, $tpar, $vpiso, $tcomi, $tgas, $ttotal){
        global $str; ##### <- place it here
            $totalPares = $tpar;
            $ventasPiso = $vpiso;
            $totalComisiones = $tcomi;
            $totalGastos = $tgas;
            $totalTotal = $ttotal;
            $str = $totalPares . "," . $ventasPiso . "," . $totalComisiones . "," . $totalGastos . "," . $totalTotal;
            return $str;
    }

    function getEm(){
        global $str; ##### <- place it here
        return $str;
    }
}
```

A sidenote: I don't really know how well codeigniter is designed, but using a global variable named `$str` sounds to me like asking for trouble. Give it a name that better reflects to what it belongs to and what it stands for. `$getValues_Helper_String` albeit string does not say much. [Some tips on finding a name](http://www.bookjive.com/wiki/Book%3aClean_Code%3a_A_Handbook_of_Agile_Software_Craftsmanship#Chapter_2%3a_Meaningful_Name).

Comment: so I basically copy/pasted this instead of my code but if I add an echo $str in the getEm() function, I get an empty space, any idea why?

Comment: Because `$str` contains an empty space. It's a variable, it contains what's in there. If you don't like what's in there, assign some other value like `$var = 'better value ;)';`.

Comment: well yeah, but that's what I'm supposedly doing in "$str = $totalPares . "," . $ven..." why is it not working there?

Comment: Rename the variable Luis. Give it a long, nice name on it's own. If still not set then you at least made the code a little bit better. And you can be sort of sure that `getValues()` has not been called prior `getEm()` - both BTW function names that ask for trouble as well IMHO.

Comment: I renamed the variables and the code snippet, still displays an empty space...I can't figure out why yet, but thanks for the help so far.

Comment: It's in what it has been set to. Is it one space or is it totally empty?

Comment: totally empty as far as I can tell

Comment: Check that you call `getValues` prior using `getEm`. Just place a `throw new Exception('getValues() has been called');` inside `getValues`. If your application does not crash, then you have not called it. If so, continue debugging. I suggest using xdbug then so you can set break points and step through your programs execution. This requires a IDE like NetBeans or Eclipse.